# Why I am getting this error : kafka.Client( ) is not a constructor?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Hi I proceeded with kafka nodejs.I am not sure why this error is coming as I did all the necessary requirements. Can anyone help me out please and below is my code -

```
var express = require('express');
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

var Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.Client(),
    producer = new Producer(client);

    producer.on('ready', function () {
        console.log('Producer is ready');
    });
    
    producer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Producer is in error state');
        console.log(err);
    })

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.json({greeting:'Kafka Producer'})
    });
    
    app.listen(4000,function(){
        console.log('Kafka producer running at 4000')
    })
```

And I am getting this error -

```
 client = new kafka.Client(),
         ^

TypeError: kafka.Client is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NITISH\kafka-nodejs\kafka.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `new kafka.Client()` isn't a constructor.

I guess it should be `new kafka.KafkaClient()`

Comment: Thanks.. Yes I used Kafka.KafkaClient( )